# how to use an attribute of an entity that has a manytomany relationship with another entity in symfony

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

i have a relation ManyToMany between two entities Doctor and insurance.
I configured my annotation ManyToMany in the entity Doctor, and in my table, Doctrine has created another separate doctor_insurance table.
now I would like to use the image attribute of an insurance to which the doctor is affiliated in my twig, but I do not know how to use this attribute

**Entity Doctor**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $assurance;

 public function __construct()
{
    $this->assurance = new ArrayCollection();
}

  /**
 * Add assurance
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance
 *
 * @return Medecin
 */
public function addAssurance(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance)
{
    $this->assurance[] = $assurance;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove assurance
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance
 */
public function removeAssurance(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance)
{
    $this->assurance->removeElement($assurance);
}

/**
 * Get assurance
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getAssurance()
{
    return $this->assurance;
}
```

**Entity Assurance**

```
  <?php

namespace Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * Assurance
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="assurance")
  * 
  */
 class Assurance
 {
  /**
  * @var int
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
private $id;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=40)
 */
public $nom;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Logo", cascade={"persist","remove","refresh"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $logo;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return Assurance
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set logo
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Media $logo
 *
 * @return Assurance
 */
public function setLogo(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Media $logo = null)
{
    $this->logo = $logo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get logo
 *
 * @return \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Media
 */
public function getLogo()
{
    return $this->logo;
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
   public function parametreAction(Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin');


    $medecin = $repo->findOneBy(array(
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
    ));

    $medecin->getAssurance();

    return $this->render('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:parametre.html.twig', array(
        'medecin' => $medecin
    ));
}
```

**Twig**

```
   <div class = "col-md-2">
       <div class="box_list photo-medecin">
             <figure>
             <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(medecin.assurance, 'logoFile') 
                 }}" class="img-fluid" alt=""> 
             </figure>

        </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assurance** means *Guarantee* / *To be sure*, So It is more likely you are after **Insurance** which is *protection against a possible eventuality.*

Also you called the first entity **Doctor**, but used it as **Medicine**, so please change this if doctor is medicine.

You need to revise your entities as they are completely wrong:

**Doctor**

```
use Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Insurance;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Doctor
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Insurance", mappedBy="doctors" cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $insurances;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->insurances = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addInsurance(Insurance $insurance)
    {
        if (!$this->insurances->contains($insurance))
        {
            $this->insurances->add($insurance);
            $insurance->addDoctor($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeInsurance(Insurance $insurance)
    {
        if ($this->insurances->contains($insurance))
        {
            $this->insurances->removeElement($insurance);
            $insurance->removeDoctor($this);
        }        
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getInsurances()
    {
        return $this->insurances;
    } 

    // ...
}
```

**Insurance**

```
use Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Doctor;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Insurance
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doctor", inversedBy="insurances")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $doctors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->doctors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addDoctor(Doctor $doctor)
    {
        if (!$this->doctors->contains($doctor))
        {
            $this->doctors->add($doctor);
            $doctor->addInsurance($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeDoctor(Doctor $doctor)
    {
        if ($this->doctors->contains($doctor))
        {
            $this->doctors->removeElement($doctor);
            $doctor->removeInsurance($this);
        }        
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getDoctors()
    {
        return $this->doctors;
    } 

    // ...
}
```

## Update

**Controller**

```
public function parametreAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $doctor = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin')->findOneBy(array(
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
    ));

    return $this->render('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:parametre.html.twig', array(
        'doctor' => $doctor
    ));
}
```

**Twig**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="box_list photo-medecin">
        {% for insurance in doctor.insurances %}
        <figure>
            <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(insurance.logo, 'logoFile') 
             }}" class="img-fluid" alt=""> 
        </figure>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Trix, 
I started from the premise that a doctor can be subscribed to 1 or more insurances for his clinic.And a given insurance ensures 1 or more doctors.So if your entity is correct how can I access the image of an insurance in my twig file?

Comment: so what do you mean by that medecin?

Comment: excuse me for my english. I speak french. In french medecin is a doctor in english.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class = "col-md-2">
{% for item in medecin.assurance %}
<div class="box_list photo-medecin">
     <figure>
     <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(item.logo , 'logoFile') 
         }}" class="img-fluid" alt=""> 
      </figure>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```